# Error while adding a new foreign key column in MySql

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE cart
    ADD COLUMN name varchar NOT NULL AFTER cartID
    FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES products(p_name);
```

> error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near 'AFTER cartID
>       FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES products(p_name)' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE cart
ADD COLUMN name varchar(10) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE cart
ADD FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES products1(p_name);
```

Check this http://rextester.com/IJFDC23276

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ALTER TABLE cart
ADD name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(name) REFERENCES products(p_name);
```